How to write to modbus register WTVB01-485?
The Modbus manual is here
In section 6.2 it talks about sending a specific sequence to the device for unlocking. How to unlock it:

send 0x50 0x06 0x00 0x69 0xB5 0x88 0x22 0xA1, (The unlocking will take effect within ten seconds).
Send the command that needs to be modified,
The third step saves the instruction: 0x50 0X06 0X00 0X00 0X00 0X84 0X4B.

Is this part 0x50 0x06 0x00 0x69 0xB5 0x88 0x22 0xA1 the equivalent of setting a register to a specific value (write enable) so I can write to other registers? Could I do all that via Radzio?
I've tried doing simple update values via Radzio with no luck

The 0x50 0x06... is a standard Modbus request (Write the value 46472 to Register 105 (PDU address)). I looks like you need to send that, then the actual write command within 10 seconds. There may be an error in the "save step", this is not a valid Modbus request; I suspect they meant 50 06 00 00 00 00 84 4B (i.e. add an extra 00, this makes the command write 00 to register 0 which aligns with the register description).

thank you Brits!! you were 100% correct :)

As Brits pointed out, you must first change Register 105 to a value of 46472 (this is the write enable command). You then have 10 seconds to change other registers before the device is put back into read only mode.
